# Concatenate element with next in the list if condition is met

Tags: scala

I'm using Stanford NLP to split text into sentences, but it ignores contraction.

So this is an example of a resulting sentence that I have:

```
List(I, 'd, like, to, fix, this, sentence, because, it, 's, broken)
```

My goal is to concatenate contracted words so that the result would look like this:

```
List(I'd, like, to, fix, this, sentence, because, it's, broken)
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this in scala? Basically I'm looking for an expression that iterates through the list checking an element with the next one, concatenating if the condition is met and returning a result list as per my example.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but note that with Stanford NLP you'll also need to address cases like `ca, n't`. You may end up wanting a more robust solution (e.g. using the part-of-speech tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val l = List("I", "'d", "like", "to fix", "this", "sentence", "because", "it", "'s", "broken")
l: List[String] = List(I, 'd, like, to fix, this, sentence, because, it, 's, broken)

scala> l.reduceRight({(s1,s2) => if (s2.startsWith("'")) s1+s2 else s1+" "+s2})
        .split(" ").toList
res2: List[String] = List(I'd, like, to, fix, this, sentence, because, it's, broken)
```

Note that this will raise an exception if the list is empty (due to the use of `reduceRight`).
You may want to use `foldRight` or `reduceRightOption` if this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
val broken = List("I", "'d", "like", "to", "fix", "this", "sentence", "because", "it", "'s", "broken")
broken.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) { (list, str) => 
  if (str.startsWith("'")) {
    list.init :+ (list.last + str) 
  } else {
    list :+ str
  }
}
```

(I assumed the "to fix" element in your question was intended to be two elements and the comma was mistakenly omitted)

Comment: For your solution: instead of using `list.slice(0, list.size - 1)`, you can use `list.init`, which exactly yields all elements except the last.

Comment: Generally I would not use `slice`, `init` and `:+` on List, since these are O(n) operations. Instead do a `foldRight` and check if the current `list.head` contains a `\``. If it does: update head, else prepend.

Comment: Thanks @Kigyo - good tips. Especially regarding `init` (I've used `tail` many times and probably should have checked if there was an inverse that would get all except last - I've edited my answer to use `init`). A fold right would be faster, but (and maybe it's just me) I find left folds more readable and typically favor code readability over performance when _n_ is small (and _n_ is usually small).

Answer (score 1):

An approach that extends accepted answer, for tackling  cases such as `ca, n't`,

```
implicit class StanfordNLPConcat(val words: List[String]) extends AnyVal {
  def SNLPConcat() = {
    val sep = "#"
    words.reduce{ (a,v) => if (v.contains("'")) a+v else a+sep+v }.split(sep).toList
  }
}
```

Let

```
val words = List("I", "'d", "like", "to", "fix", "this", "sentence", "because", "it", "'s", "broken")
```

and so

```
words.SNLPConcat()
res:  List[String] = List(I'd, like, to, fix, this, sentence, because, it's, broken)
```

Further,

```
List("It", "ca", "n't", "be", "wrong").SNLPConcat()
res: List[String] = List(It, can't, be, wrong)
```