# Predicate doesnt return anything with span

Tags: scala

I have done some tests using the following list found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855645/concatenate-element-with-next-in-the-list-if-condition-is-met)

If I try to group the items of the list which are less than N characters using `span`, it returns me an Empty List

```
scala> val list = List("I", "'d", "like", "to fix", "this", "sentence", "because", "it", "'s", "broken")
list: List[String] = List(I, 'd, like, to fix, this, sentence, because, it, 's, broken)

scala> list span ( _.length > 1) // The predicate doesnt match anything: Empty list
res36: (List[String], List[String]) = (List(),List(I, 'd, like, to fix, this, sentence, because, it, 's, broken))

scala> list map ( _.length)
res37: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 7, 2, 2, 6)

scala> val list = List("Hello","World","Foo","Bar","Donald", "Duck")
list: List[String] = List(Hello, World, Foo, Bar, Donald, Duck)

scala> list span ( _.length > 1)
res38: (List[String], List[String]) = (List(Hello, World, Foo, Bar, Donald, Duck),List())
```

Can anyone explain me what's going on?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `span` and `partition` :

- `partition` splits a list in 2 according to a predicate `p`
- `span` splits a list into 2 parts : (until `p` is false, rest of list)

From the documentation : `Note: c span p is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) (c takeWhile p, c dropWhile p)`

Here the predicate `(_.length > 1)` fails on the first element, so `span` return `(List(),List(I, 'd, like, to fix, this, sentence, because, it, 's, broken))`

Answer (score 2):

`span` is like `takeWhile` except that it returns the rest of the list starting with the first failed match. Since your predicate fails on the first element of the list, you get the result you're seeing.

If you want all the elements that pass/fail the predicate you can use `partition` instead:

```
list partition ( _.length > 1)
```

if you only need the elements that pass the predicate you can use `filter`:

```
list filter ( _.length > 1)
```